# Sort python list basis another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following master list:

```
[
   {'entity': 'Country', 'cnt': 4},
   {'entity': 'State', 'cnt': 3},
   {'entity': 'City', 'cnt': 2}
]
```

Note the order of the entities.

I wish to order another list based on the order of entities in the first list.

Second list:

```
[
   {'entity': 'State', 'values': 'AK'},
   {'entity': 'Country', 'values': 'USA'}
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
   {'entity': 'Country', 'values': 'USA'},
   {'entity': 'State', 'values': 'AK'}
]
```

I tried the following:

```
secondList.sort(key=lambda x: firstList.index(x["entity"]))
```

However, it gives me an error since City is not found in the second list.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you explain more clearly the reasoning for the output ordering?  Is the value of 'cnt' involved in anyway, or is the position within the "master list"?

Comment: Perhaps it's more worth organizing the dictionaries, then it is to organize the list. Why not just have nested dictionaries? `{'United States': {'Florida': {'Miami': '...'}, 'Georgia': {'Atlanta': '...'}}}`

Comment: yes, 'cnt' is used in the program to order the master list. it is done before we come to this part of the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could maybe make a bit preprocessing:

```
master = [
   {'entity': 'Country', 'cnt': 4},
   {'entity': 'State', 'cnt': 3},
   {'entity': 'City', 'cnt': 2}
]

to_sort = [
   {'entity': 'State', 'values': 'AK'},
   {'entity': 'Country', 'values': 'USA'}
]

prep = { record['entity'] : i for  i, record in enumerate(master)  }


sorted(to_sort, key = lambda x: prep[x['entity']])
```

Comment: One note of caution, if an entity occurs more than once in the first list this solution will order it based on its last occurence.

Comment: If that's undesired behavior and you want it based on the first occurrence you can replace `enumerate(master)` with `reversed(list(enumerate(master)))`.

Comment: @ChristianSloper thanks! so, you're suggesting to convert to a dictionary first of my master list and then use it on my second list?

Comment: Not converting anything, but creating an extra dicitonary that can help you with sorting.

Comment: thank you, kindly! i just tried out your suggestion for this and it gives me the desired result!

Answer (score 1):

As @Christian mentions you can do a bit of pre-processing. If that is not an option you can do the following, however performance *will be worse* this way.

```
def custom_sort(item):
    key = item['entity']
    for idx, ent in enumerate(master):
        if key == ent['entity']:
            return idx

sorted(data, key=custom_sort)

[{'entity': 'Country', 'values': 'USA'}, {'entity': 'State', 'values': 'AK'}]
```